# calculate the mean of a group while keeping columns of type object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like following:

```
col1   col2 col3 col4   col5...
g1       x1   x2   x3     x4
g1       x5   x6   x7     x8
g2       y1   y2   y3     y4
g2       y5   y6   y7     y8
...
```

where col1/col2 are of type "object" and col3/col4/col5 are of type "float"

I wanna first groupby col1 and then calculate the mean value of col3/col4/col5, while keeping col2 in the result dataframe. By "keeping" I simply mean leaving it as it is, without even calculating the mean, which is impossible, as it's of type "object". The actual values of each row of col2 in each group are the same, picking anyone will be fine.

If I do it naively in this way:

```
df.groupby(["col1"]).mean().reset_index()
```

then the result dataframe will not keep col2,col2 is gone. That is, the result will be like following:

```
col1           col3          col4          col5...
g1        (x2+y2)/2     (x3+y3)/2     (x4+y4)/2
g2        (x6+y6)/2     (x7+x8)/2     (x8+y8)/2
```

How can I calculate the mean of col3/col4/col5 while keeping col2(leaving it unchanged)?

Comment: How can you "keep" `col2`? It has different values for each row, which one would you pick?

Comment: Guess you might need transform if you want to retain all rows of `col2`  `df.assign(**df.groupby("col1")['col3','col4','col5'].transform('mean'))`

Comment: @Nick, By "keep" I mean just leaving the value as it is for each row without any modifications

Comment: Your original dataframe has multiple rows for `g1`, `g2` etc., but the output only has 1. So how do you decide what value goes in the output row?

Comment: Ah it's my fault, actually, the value of each row of col2 for each group is the same, so just picking anyone is fine

Comment: If `col2` is the same for every `col1` value you could just group by it as well

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to pick a value of "col2"

- generate mean as you want
- join pack onto columns you want to keep,  picking first one

```
s = 20
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":np.random.choice(["g1","g2","g3"],s),
             "col2":np.random.choice(["constant"],s),
             **{f"col{i+3}":np.random.randint(1,10,s) for i in range(3)}})

df.groupby("col1").mean().join(df.groupby(["col1"])["col2"].first() ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

|  | col3 | col4 | col5 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5.875 | 6.75 | 6.75 | constant |
| 1 | 7 | 5.33333 | 6 | constant |
| 2 | 4.77778 | 4.88889 | 3.66667 | constant |